# Significato di "darsi un'altra occasione"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Quello stesso giorno entrò al banco dei pegni del padre di Moe Rosen e gli affidò la catenina con la croce di Vita. L’aveva custodita per tutto questo tempo, soffrendo la fame inutilmente, pur di conservarla. Era il suo talismano e l’unico segno visibile della promessa che si erano scambiati. Invece, con i dollari che ne ricavò, **si diede un’altra occasione**. RAGAZZA ITALIANA SPARITA. Sparita per tutti ma soprattutto per lui.  Non voleva mai piú sentir parlare di Vita – e l’America era abbastanza grande per regalargli quest’oblio. Si fece scrivere dal vecchio riccioluto l’indirizzo di Moe a Denver, Colorado, e mandò un telegramma al suo vecchio amico. THERE IS A GIOBBA FOR DIAMANTE? FACCIO EVERYTING.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa l'espressione "darsi un'altra occasione" che appare in questo brano? Non sono riuscita a trovarla su nessun dizionario.

Comment: Credo che il significato qui sia proprio letterale: la persona in questione utilizzò i proventi della vendita della croce per un'altra chance ad una vita più stabile (è difficile capire più dettagli senza contesto).

Comment: Concordo con l'interpretazione di @Denis Nardin. Il personaggio ha dato (a se stesso) la possibilità di iniziare una nuova fase della sua vita. La vendita della collana rappresenta una cesura con il passato.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ho aggiunto alcune righe del testo per dare un po' più de contesto. Penso, però, che il significato sia quello che hai detto tu. Questo personaggio, Diamante, decide di andarsene a lavorare a Denver. Potreste scriverlo come risposta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi sembra che qua il significato sia proprio quello letterale. Il protagonista vende la catenina con la croce di Vita, e usa i proventi per pagarsi il viaggio a Denver, dove spera di aver l'occasione di cominciare una nuova vita.